# Откуда на сервере jboss берется значение для JSESSIONID?

Tags: jboss, servlet, сессия, java, сервер

***(изменил)***
Исследую ошибку на продакшен-сервере, которая не воспроизводится на других серверах (с таким же приложением). Выяснил, что у всех имеется кука JSESSIONID, которая имеет вид JSESSIONID=**хардыбарды.appname** , где appname имя приложения. И вот обнаружил, что когда приложение **appname** выполняет ту самую ошибку (после аутентификации), значение JSESSIONID, равняется то **хардыбарды.appname-a**, то  **хардыбарды.appname-b** (название условно).

Comment: Пока нашел, что это, похоже, связанно с Clustering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого сервера имеется схема реализации механизма сессий - по-научному это называется *Session Management*. Грубо говоря, вендор сервера волен в реализации интерфейса `HttpSession` (и не только его) так, как ему удобно. JBoss реализует это через куки с идентификаторами `JSESSIONID`.

В принципе некоторые сервера допускают изменение менеджера сессий, есть подключаемые менеджеры сессий - так что не все так однозначно.

**Update**

> Можно ли задать значение имени сессии как-нибудь самому?

Это называется [Session Replay Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) или по-другому при обнаружении злого умысла [ст. 272 УК РФ - Неправомерный доступ к компьютерной информации](http://www.zakonrf.info/uk/272/) - так что имейте в виду. :)

Comment: Оказалось, что сессия теряется где-то в цепочке фильтров, поэтому вопрос теперь будет звучать "Как и где может теряться сессия" или т.п., так, что корректнее будет разместить его как новый. Но ваш ответ принимаю, так как он дает полезную информацию именно на этот вопрос, кроме того, содержит полезный призыв к почитанию УК.